# VariantChangeType and overflow

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, com, variant

As I understand it, [`VariantChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258.aspx) is supposed to correctly detect overflows and return `DISP_E_OVERFLOW` if an overflow occurs. However, I have found at least one case where this does not occur. Does anyone have any insight into this? I am using Windows 7, VS2013, VC++2008.

```
VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
v.vt = VT_UI2;
v.uiVal = 32768;
HRESULT hr = VariantChangeType(&v, &v, 0, VT_I2);
```

With the code above, I would expect that `hr` would be equal to `DISP_E_OVERFLOW`. However, `S_OK` is returned from `VariantChangeType` and the value of the `VARIANT v` is `-32768` (exactly what I expect from 16-bit integer overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258.aspx) for `VariantChangeType()` states:

> DISP_E_OVERFLOW
>   The data pointed to by pvarSrc does not fit in the destination type.

If the conversion from `VT_UI2` to `VT_I2` succeeds for 32768, that suggests to me that a `VT_UI2` value fits in a `VT_I2`, even if it wraps to a negative value.

Let's say the variant held a `VT_UI4` instead.  If the value were > 32767, that could not be converted to `VT_I2`, and should report `DISP_E_OVERFLOW`.

On the other hand, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221327.aspx) for `VarI2FromUI2()` says the same thing for `DISP_E_OVERFLOW`, and `VarI2FromUI2()` actually does fail with `DISP_E_OVERFLOW` for an input value of 32768.

So that would suggest that `VariantChangeType()` is either broken for this conversion, or it is using a different set of conversion rules, maybe for legacy reasons.

Comment: After much debate, I'm going to give this the answer. See my comment to @Hans below.

Answer (score 3):

Think of this the other way around.  What if you wanted to create scripting language that *does* support conversions like this?  Not uncommon, C# and C behave this way for example.  If VariantChangeType() would disallow this then you couldn't implement this conversion.

You *can* get an overflow if you need it.  You must convert to VT_UI4 first, then to VT_I2.  That  fails with a values 32768 and up.

Comment: After some debate, I'm going to give the answer to @Remy. Your point certainly isn't without merit. However, I think of it more like this: VariantChangeType can do things like converting strings to dates. This is a semantic conversion, not a bit-level conversion. I would think the best design of such a function would be to have it work entirely one way or entirely the other way. I believe the true intent of VariantChangeType is semantic conversions. As such, I view this either as a bug or a design flaw.

Comment: From a *semantic* perspective, it probably makes sense for an unsigned 32768 to be converted to a signed -32768 without error. A lot of areas of the Win32 API depend on passing a signed int -1 where unsigned int values are expected, and vice versa. So at least for same-size conversions, maybe for all conversions, the behavior of `VariantChangeType()` is probably intentional, albeit undocumented.